# Python 3: parse html with XPath error

Tags: html, xpath, python-3.5

I am new to python 3. I am paring the html data with XPath. I use the pycharm to compile my code, my code is shown as following. please help me fix the issue (please don't use the beautiful soup).I know a lot code about parse html with python 2 xpath, if you have some materials link about parse html with python 3 xpath, please tell me.  I have installed the lxml and requests library in the pycharm. Further, the terminal default is python 2.7.Thanks in advance!

```
  from lxml import html
  import requests

  page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
  tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

  #This will create a list of buyers:
  buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
  #This will create a list of prices
  prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

  print('Buyers: ', buyers)
  print('Prices: ', prices)
```

The errors:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5     
/Users/tianke0711/PycharmProjects/database/Pax_html/xpath_test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File     
 "/Users/tianke0711/PycharmProjects/database/Pax_html/xpath_test.py", 
 line 1, in <module>
from lxml import html
  File   

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-   
packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
from .. import etree
```

ImportError:

ddlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0

Comment: If you want more information about this error, please tell me! I hope you guys could help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error information,the libxml2.2( Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib) is the old version. Since the python3 need new version of libxml. Use the following command to install the new libxml, and then it works for me.

```
brew install libxml2
brew install libxslt
brew link libxml2 --force
brew link libxslt --force
```

Actually, I don't know the reason in detail. If some guys know this, please tell me! Thanks!